# Why "Expected to decode Data but found an array instead" I have no arrays in my code

Tags: swift, nsdata, codable

I have this codable struct:

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    let rect: CGRect
    let image: UIImage

    init(rect: CGRect, image: UIImage) {
        self.rect = rect
        self.image = image
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(rect, forKey: .rect)
        try container.encode(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), forKey: .image)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        rect = try container.decode(CGRect.self, forKey: .rect)
        image = try UIImage(data: container.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image))!
    }

    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case rect
        case image
    }
}
```

Now I create a `Foo` and attempt to encode it and decode it:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my_image")
let foo = Foo(rect: .zero, image: image!)
let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
let data = try! encoder.encode(foo)
let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
try! decoder.decode(Foo.self, from: data)
```

Now at the `decode` line, this error occurs:

> Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Foundation.Data, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [__lldb_expr_244.Foo.CodingKeys.image], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Data but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Apparently the decoder found an array while trying to decode the image data. Why does this happen? It seems that somehow the `Data` becomes an array. I am very confused because

```
Data() is Codable
```

evaluates to true, so the coders should theoretically be able to en/decode a `Data`. Why does it become an array?

Edit: I'm using Xcode 9.1

Here is `my_image`:

[image]

Comment: Tried such code in a new project, I don't see any error.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini Can you run it in a playground?

Comment: It works fine, of course I had to add an image into Playground->Resources

Comment: That's weird... I'll wait and see if others can reproduce this.

Comment: Ok, in the meantime if you want to check my test: https://github.com/mugx/playgroundtest

Comment: I deleted the other comment because I was wrong. The code is supposed to work.

Comment: @vadian Can you not reproduce it? That's weird. I pasted the code that Andrea Mugnanini wrote into my playground and the same thing happens. Could this has something to do with my locale or something like that?

Comment: Yes I can reproduce it, I tested it in a playground. I would try another image.

Comment: Everything seems to be working to me too, my guess is either something within Xcode9.1 (I'm testing against 9.2) or something with the image, can you attach the actual image you're using here to rule out that part ?

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg the image is just my profile pic. Xcode version shouldn't matter right? This seems like a swift issue.

Comment: I see, do you have any other image that's not a private pic that reproduces ? well Swift might be the same, but the Swift complier and Swift SDK usually include changes and bugfixes, so it's not always 100% the same

Comment: @MostafaTorbjørnBerg It's not a private pic. You can just go to my profile and download it. Anyway, edited the question.

Comment: Perfect, I thought it's like a facebook pic or so ;), Ok tried it now but can't reproduce, i'll try to download Xcode 9.1 and see if i start getting the issues, will report shortly

Comment: Works for me in an Xcode 9.2 playground. Any reason you can't upgrade? Also: test with another image. Does the error persist?

Comment: I tested another JPG image and the error persists. And yes I can update, but I am just curious why this is. @Gereon

Comment: @Sweeper good news, I tested with Xcode 9.1 and now i can see your error, so that means it's resolved in Xcode 9.2, i'll take a look now and investigate why this happens on 9.1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a bug, it seems like the issue is during the encoding process, when encoding the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` data, which is returned as `Optional` things go really wrong, if you change the `encode` method to force the data like this:

```
container.encode(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!, forKey: .image)
```

instead of:

```
container.encode(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), forKey: .image)
```

Things will work both in Xcode 9.1 and 9.2, if you leave the data optional as it is, the encoding will work only on 9.2 and fail 9.1, for some reason the image data size will be doubled on 9.1.

I'm pretty sure it's [this bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5710) on swift.org

Which also mentions that it causes memory usage double the size of the data, which is what I'm seeing on my local setup.

So the easy way around is to force the `UIImagePNGRepresentation(..)` data or upgrade to 9.2 where this bug is fixed.

Hope this answered your question, very interesting find indeed!

Comment: Did you find out why it finds an array?

Comment: it can be many reasons and I didn't go into the actual PR that fixes it, but i'm pretty sure if you look at the [code there](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/11605/files) you'll see it wasn't properly boxing the values, my guess without looking deeply into the code is that it either defaulted to an array, or the data for some reason got encoded as an array when it was optional, if i get time during the week i'll take a look and see if i can pinpoint the exact place where the issue occurs and update my answer :)